# Javascript sum of values to work with Parsley

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

I have this code that I need to work with Parsly.js - How do I shoehorn this into their structure so it displays the correct message to user. Here is a link to an example of the group validation
[parsley group validation](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/custom-validator-events.html)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#some-form").validate({

        rules: {
            TextBox1: {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
            },
            TextBox2 : {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
            }
            TextBox3 : {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
            }
            TextBox4 : {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
            }

        },
        submitHandler: function(form){
            var total = parseInt($("#TextBox1").val()) + parseInt($("#TextBox2").val()) + parseInt($("#TextBox3").val()) + parseInt($("#TextBox4").val());
            if (total != 100) {
                $(".error").html("Your total must sum to 100.")
                return false;
            } else form.submit();
        }

    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: You adapt that example to your use case... :-)

Comment: Could you show an example?  I am new to Parsley

Comment: Why don't you try it, starting from the example you posted (click on the CodePen button) and post your attempt here...